# Latex output generated using Doxygen does not support nested groups (defgroup within a defgroup)

Tags: latex, doxygen, hierarchy, nested-groups

I have been trying to find a way to retain the hierarchy of groups (`defgroup` defined within a `defgroup`) in a PDF generated using LaTeX files (generated using Doxygen). For example, if I use:

```
/** @defgroup group3 The Third Group
 *  This is the third group
 */

/** @defgroup group4 The Fourth Group
 *  @ingroup group3
 *  Group 4 is a subgroup of group 3
 */
```

I expect the "The Fourth Group" to appear under the "The Third Group" in the PDF. For example:

```
1.2 The Third Group
1.2.1 The Fourth Group
```

It is important to note that the HTML output preserves the hierarchy. But in PDF, both the groups appears at the same hierarchy under "Module Documentation". For example:

```
1.2 The Third Group
1.3 The Fouth Group
```

Do we have a workaround/possible fix for the issue? Because of the issue, I am not able to ship the PDF file, generated using Doxygen, to my customers.

Comment: Hi All, Please help me with a fix to the issue. The generated PDF with flattened module hierarchy is confusing and not helpful.

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem as well.